# angular js bootstrap ng-repeat behaving wierd - drag drop not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to display some data as widgets inside ng-repeat but angular is behaving wierd. I don't seem to understand what is causing this. The HTML where I am trying to put ng-repeat is this.

```
<div class="span3 widget-container-span">
                                <div class="widget-box">

                                    <div class="widget-header widget-header-small header-color-dark">
                                        <h6 class="smaller">{{ me.head }}</h6>

                                        <div class="widget-toolbar no-border">
                                            <label>
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="ace ace-switch ace-switch-3" />
                                                <span class="lbl"></span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="widget-toolbar">
                                            <span class="label label-warning">
                                                1.2%
                                                <i class="icon-arrow-down"></i>
                                            </span>
                                            <span class="badge badge-info">{{ me.label }}</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="widget-body">
                                        <div class="widget-main">
                                            <div class="alert alert-info">
                                                {{ me.desc }}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div> <!-- end widget box-->
                            </div><!-- end span3 widget container-->
```

If I put ng-repeat on the first div (span3 widget-container-span), the widget dragging does not work. [image: widget container dragging not woking]

If I put the ng-repeat in second div (div class = "widget box"), drag and drop capability works but boxes come vertically stacked not horizontally and spacing between them is uncounted. Its like a column drag and drop. [image: widget container drag working but only vertical]

My guess - Container div stops to work when use angular ng-repeat.

Please guide what I am missing.

P.S. I am using partials.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Looking at your screenshot, it looks like you're using the ACE template (so am I).  I haven't done too much troubleshooting yet, in fact your question is hit #1 for me :)  Please post an update if you find a resolution.

Comment: @BennettDill I will post the solution soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a directive to avoid sortable conflict of jquery with angular

```
myScrum.directive("ngSortable", function(){
return {
    link: function(scope, linkElement, attrs){                  
        linkElement.sortable({
            placeholder: "placeholder",
            opacity: 0.8,
            axis: "x,y",
            update: function(event, ui) {
                // get model
                var model = scope.$eval(attrs.ngSortable);

               // loop through items in new order
                linkElement.children().each(function(index) {
                    var item = $(this);

                    // get old item index
                    var oldIndex = parseInt(item.attr("ng-sortable-index"), 10);

                    model[oldIndex].seq = index;
                });
                // notify angular of the change
                scope.$apply();
            }
        });
    }
};
});
```

and used following in the div

```
<div class="widget-box" ng-sortable-index="{{$index}}" ng-repeat="item in sid">
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  I'll take a look and see if it fixes my problem too :)